# If I rent a container and put some square sized packages

Tags: real-analysis

If I rent a container and put some square sized packages

The container has a width of 25, length 43, and height 62
And I have a package that has to be sent with dimensions of width 7, length 6 and height 5.

So how many packages can I put in the container to be sent?

Comment: What is a "square sized package", and how does that description apply to a package with dimensions seven by six by five?

Comment: It’s a box/cube

Comment: A seven by six by five cube? Please, Dary, what is your definition of cube?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The container has a volume of $25*43*62=66650$. Each box has a volume of $5*6*7=210$. So you certainly will not get more than $\lfloor \frac{66650}{210} \rfloor = 317$ boxes in the container.

It is easy to fill $25\times 42\times 60$ by $5\times 7\times 6$ boxes. This takes $5*6*10=300$ boxes. But we can do better.

Since $25$ is divisible by $5$, let's build $5$ layers of $5$ units thick. This reduces it to the 2-dimensional problem of filling a $43\times62$ rectangle by as many $6\times7$ rectangles as possible.

You can get at most $\lfloor \frac{43*62}{6*7} \rfloor = 63$ rectangles in there, and this bound can be achieved like this:

[image]

Using $5$ such layers lets you put $5*63=315$ boxes in the container. This does not quite reach the upper bound of $317$, but I don't think you can do better.

Comment: $300$ five by seven by six boxes take a volume of $63000$. $25\times43\times62=66650$. So there's an unused volume of $3650$, not $50$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thanks for pointing that out the mistake. I was rushed when first writing my answer and now with some more time I completely rewrote it. It is now close to optimal.